# yii2 передать параметры в get запрос activerecord

Tags: php, yii2

Привет
Нужно сделать выборку из БД по критерием.
т.е. при обращении к странице сайта (записи в бд), в строке есть данные (`ID` других строк) нужно выбрать все строки где эти записи повторяются.

```
SELECT * FROM `pedigrees` WHERE `sire`=733 AND `dam`=731
```

В модели пишу:

```
public function getSiblings(){
    $sibling = Pedigrees::find()
      ->where(['sire' => $sire, 'dam' => $dam])
      ->all();
    return $sibling;
```

Вопрос: как поместить данные полей `sire` `dam` в `$sire` `$dam`?
С `ID` строки просто `$id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');`, но тут как-то не соображу.

Comment: откровенно говоря, ничего не понятно. С чем проблема? Как передать параметры в контроллер или как передать в модель?

Comment: запрос отрабатывает в модели

Comment: мда, ну пусть отрабатывает, что уж тут